# Tweak language of 'move this discussion to chat' link

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, comments

When there are a large number of comments on a post, you are prompted with this if you go to add another comment:

> Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

I'd like to request that this say that you're **copying** the discussion to chat instead of moving.  The expectation from most computer users is that a move removes it from the source, and places it in the destination.  A copy operation instead leaves the original in place, while making a duplicate in the destination.  The latter is what this link does, but the text implies the former.

And yes, I realize this is a pretty nitpicky grammar request.

Comment: Depends; Is the previous discussion an rvalue reference or not?

Answer (score 4):

No, you're not copying the discussion to chat, you're moving it. For one thing, further comments will not be copied to chat. For another, it's the *discussion* that's being moved, not the comments. And to trump it all, for a non-programmer, you *move* a discussion to another venue. “Copying a discussion” sounds like the discussion is over and you're sending a recording to a third party.

Comment: Hm. How about a compromise (my original proposal) - AFTER clicking the link, you are presented with a pop-up showing the link to newly created chat, AND the explanation of what/why happened and what is expected further.